# Accessing the Evernote API through Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, evernote

I have a bunch of notes in Evernote which I would like to access in a Rubyish way (instead of only using the web interface). I thought I'd use this gem (https://github.com/cgs/evernote), which is "...a high level wrapper around Evernote's Thrift-generated ruby code. It bundles up Evernote's thrift-generated code and creates some simple wrapper classes."

I got a developer key, and the sample code here (https://github.com/cgs/evernote/blob/master/example.rb) worked, giving me the correct name for my sandbox notebook.

However, I don't understand what to do next. By "simple wrapper classes" I was expecting the  Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook object to be some Enumerable object that I could use blocks to query. I dunno, something like

notebook.select {|note| note.tags == 'foo'}

But when I do the notebook.TAB TAB trick in IRB to look at available methods, there is nothing like that. The author of the gem refers users to Evernote API at http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/ , and I can't make heads or tails of the thing. Am I out of luck until I fully understand what things like THRIFT means, or is there a simple listing of methods somewhere that I'm failing to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have to learn anything about Thrift. The data model wrapper classes (Note, Notebook, Tag, etc) are basically dumb structs; the methods to exercise them are on the endpoint classes, UserStore and NoteStore. For example, to get a list of Notebooks, you'd call [NoteStore.listNotebooks](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listNotebooks). You can see some examples in the [SDK](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/) under ruby/sample.

Comment: Thank you, Seth. I'll muddle around with those.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue recently, to use Ruby accessing the Evernote API. And here is the list which may help:

- [Official Ruby Demo](https://github.com/evernote/simple-api-client-example-ruby)
- [Evernote Developer Guide](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/ruby.php)
- [Evernote API: All declarations](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/)
- [ENML](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php)

And I wrote a demo to make it more specific and straight.

- [Evernote API Ruby demo](https://github.com/ifyouseewendy/evernote-api-ruby-demo)